# Generic function argument affecting the return type with default implementation

Tags: typescript

Given the following (obviously simplified) function

```
function maybeTransform(transform) {
  const myString = "abc";
  return transform ? transform(myString) : myString;
}
```

Is there a way to express this properly in Typescript?
I tried about a million things but couldn't get it to work.

I also have no problem with adding a no-op default transform to make this work. But I always end up with a variation of `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'` (assuming T is the return type of the transform and the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this either with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) or [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types).  Differing numbers of parameters seems to work better with overloads, like this:

```
function maybeTransform(): "abc";
function maybeTransform<R>(transform: (arg: string)=>R): R;
function maybeTransform(transform?: (arg: string)=>any) {
  const myString = "abc";
  return transform ? transform(myString) : myString;
}
const x = maybeTransform(); // "abc"
const y = maybeTransform((x: string) => x.length); // number
```

You could also try conditional types, but it gets funky with the possible `undefined`-ness of the argument:

```
function maybeTransform<F extends undefined | ((arg: string) => any) = undefined>(
  transform?: F
): F extends (arg: string) => infer R ? R : "abc" {
  const myString = "abc";
  return transform ? transform(myString) : myString;
}
const x = maybeTransform(); // "abc"
const y = maybeTransform((x: string) => x.length); // number
```

Neither method does too well with a parameter whose type is possibly undefined:

```
const whoKnows = Math.random()<0.5 ? undefined : ((x: string)=>x.length);
const xOrY = maybeTransform(whoKnows);
```

With overloads it doesn't compile (`type '((x: string) => number) | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(arg: string) => number'`); with conditional types it gives the wrong result type (`number`).  So there are caveats.  I think I prefer overloads in this case, since I'd rather be prevented from making a valid call then be given an invalid return type.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Nice! The overloads did the trick. - Using the conditionals solution has a big issue: `maybeTransform<(arg: string) => number>();` compiles even though it misses the transform.